# Read XML file in S3 using SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, saxparser

I need to read xml file which locates in S3 using SAXParser. I found lots of examples about how to read a normal in S3, but there is no any material related to my question.

The reason for me to use SAXParser is to because I need validate the XML file. The below is the code sample to validate a local xml file.

```
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(entitiesScriptSchema);
System.out.println(path);
Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File(path));
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(xmlFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get an `InputStream` of the S3 object via:

`InputStream s3stream = s3Client.getObject("bucket", "key").getObjectContent();`

Then you should be able to pass the `InputStream` to the SAX Parser just like any other Java `InputStream`.

Comment: You mean put the input stream to here? Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File(path));

Comment: Yes change that line to `Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(s3stream);`